# PIG: Select records from a relaltion only if it is present in another relation

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have the following data set for a movie database:

```
Ratings: UserID, MovieID, Rating
Movies: MovieID, Genre
```

I filtered out the movies with Genres as "Action" or "War" using:

```
movie_filter = filter Movies by (genre matches '.*Action.*') OR (genre matches '.*War.*');
```

Now, I have to calculate the average ratings for War or Action movies. But the ratings is present in the Ratings file. To do this, I use the query:

```
movie_groups = GROUP movie_filter BY MovieID;

result = FOREACH movie_groups GENERATE Ratings.MovieID, AVG(Ratings.rating);
```

Then I store the result in a directory location. But when I run the program, I get the following error:

```
Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.builtin.AVG as multiple or none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast.
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're missing a join statement, which would join your two data sets (ratings & movies) on the MovieID column.  I've mocked up some test data, and provided some example code below.

**movie_avg.pig**

```
ratings = LOAD 'movie_ratings.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (user_id:chararray, movie_id:chararray, rating:int);
movies = LOAD 'movie_data.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (movie_id:chararray,genre:chararray);

movies_filter = FILTER movies BY (genre MATCHES '.*Action.*' OR genre MATCHES '.*War.*');

movies_join = JOIN movies_filter BY movie_id, ratings BY movie_id;

movies_cleanup = FOREACH movies_join GENERATE movies_filter::movie_id AS movie_id, ratings::rating as rating;

movies_group = GROUP movies_cleanup by movie_id;

data = FOREACH movies_group GENERATE group, AVG(movies_cleanup.rating);

dump data;
```

**Output of movie_avg.pig**

```
(Jarhead,3.0)
(Platoon,4.333333333333333)
(Die Hard,3.0)
(Apocolypse Now,4.5)
(Last Action Hero,2.0)
(Lethal Weapon, 4.0)
```

**movie_data.txt**

```
Scrooged,Comedy
Apocolypse Now,War
Platoon,War
Guess Whos Coming To Dinner,Drama
Jarhead,War
Last Action Hero,Action
Die Hard,Action
Lethal Weapon,Action
My Fair Lady,Musical
Frozen,Animation
```

**movie_ratings.txt**

```
12345,Scrooged,4
12345,Frozen,4
12345,My Fair Lady,5
12345,Guess Whos Coming To Dinner,5
12345,Platoon,3
12345,Jarhead,2
23456,Platoon,5
23456,Apocolypse Now,4
23456,Die Hard,3
23456,Last Action Hero,2
34567,Lethal Weapon,4
34567,Jarhead,4
34567,Apocolypse Now,5
34567,Platoon,5
34567,Frozen,5
```